# Почему расстановка знаков препинания в первом случае неверна?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, кавычки

> 1. Слово "способ", бывает, употребляется некорректно. **Например, "с** речевыми способами сообразуется мышление"

и

> 2. Слово "способ", бывает, употребляется некорректно. **Например: с** речевыми способами сообразуется мышление

Почему первый вариант пунктуации неправилен?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в этом варианте непонятно, к чему пример.   Слово **например** в качестве вводного слова с запятой указывает на последовательность мыслей в последующей части  предложения. *Слово "способ", бывает, употребляется некорректно*. *Например, "с речевыми способами сообразуется мышление"*. Два самостоятельных предложения.

Двоеточие привязывает **например** к предыдущей фразе.
*Слово "способ", бывает, употребляется некорректно.
Например: "с речевыми способами сообразуется мышление"*. Понятно, что за первым предложением последует пример некорректного употребления. Это парцеллированная конструкция, она воспринимается как одно целое.

Comment: А употребление кавычек ведь в данном случае обязательно?

Comment: Но ведь это же чья-то некорректная фраза? Это же чужая речь? Значит, в кавычках.